# Get ID of the current Calendar - Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016

I'm trying to get the current calendar list ID, This works

```
SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
```

but only when I select on something on the calendar, is there something else I can try that doesn't require calendar selection?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean "current" on the `calendar.aspx`-page?

Comment: I can get the GUID of calendar list from default calendar view(Calendar.asps page) using `SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();` without selecting anything on calendar.